# How to keep Angular 6 JS Listeners to a minimum with +4000-5000 form fields

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, formarray

Working on an app for reporting timesheet information for site resources. For various locations there can be upwards of 500-600 line items, each line item has at least 16 form-fields, though only 8 have an HTML component 'assigned'.

the general form lay-out looks like this:
[image]
Each line-item is it's own form component in a `FormArray`, which is part of the parent form. The form itself is 'managed' by a form service that handles most of the retrieval of data and adding and deleting of line items.

The generation of the FormArry gets done in the `formService`

```
//Initiate listener on service
this.service.getDate.subscribe((data: IInterface[]) => {
      data.map(lineitem => {
          const array = this.getFormArray(lineitem.group);
          lineitem.id = array.length + 1;
          let iform = this.fb.group(new LineItemForm(lineitem));
          array.push(iform);
      });
  });
```

The ini for the data gets triggered by a single call from the parent-form on a button click, the above listener distributes the data over 4 individual arrays by means of the `lineitem.group`.
That all works as supposed to.

In the parent form HTML the lineitem-forms get generated as follows and the `Array` comes from the `formService` where it gets filtered by page number into a static Array (i.e. the service doesn't need to call or filter upon retrieving the array in the Parent as that was already done on retrieval of the data. the `Array` should therefore be 'ready-to-serve')

```
<lineitem *ngFor="let lineitem of Array?.controls; let i = index"
              [index]="i"
              [LineItemForm]="lineitem"
              (deleteLineItem)="deleteLineItem($event)">
 </lineitem>
```

the lineitem-form component has following spec's and properties.

After the lineitem View is rendered each lineitem-form gets detached from the ChangeDetection process and all subscriptions are pushed into an array so we can unsubscribe from all upon ngOnDestroy. At the moment there are only 3 subscription listeners initiated. (1 for the employee typeahead, one for the employee array (which comes from the service and one for resources array (also from service))

```
@Component({
    selector: 'lineitem',
    templateUrl: './lineitem.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./lineitem.component.css', './../form.component.css'],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
 })

constructor(
    private formService: formService,
    private modalService: BsModalService,
    private cd: ChangeDetectorRef
) {        
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.cd.detach();
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscriptions.forEach(c => c.unsubscribe());
}
```

The fields for Monday - Sunday have a `(change)` binding to a calculation method in the form-component, at the end of the method the `ChangeDetectionRef` is triggered to run the `this.cd.detectChanges()` to update each individual lineitem-form.

```
calculateThings(){

    // … do some calculations and form-field sets

    //Trigger change detection cycle
    this.cd.detectChanges();
}
```

The Parent-form is set to `ChangeDetection.Default` (though switching it to `OnPush` doesn't reduce the quantity of listeners)

To solve (part of) the problem, I have separated the overall quantity of line-items in tabs, each tab gets only generated when actually displayed using an `*ngIf` binding. This reduces the amount of listeners to about 2000-4000 on the active tab. However, if a user clicks back and forth between two tabs, the listeners quickly start adding up again.

At some stage -though irregular and without clear 'reason'- the listener count resets again to a more manageable 2000-3000 (still a lot but that works) I can display around 35-50 lines (i.e. about 300-400 formfields) before there is noticeable delay in response time.

This leads to a couple of questions:

1. Is there a method to 'purge' listeners, when moving from tab to tab (i.e. when re-generating the DOM)
2. Is there any way in which to 'reset' the DOM so the listener count drops to near zero
3. What is the best (or recommended) way to handle this amount of lines/form-field
   (if I look at ag-Grid for example, they seem to be able to generate 10000 lines @ 100 columns, without exceeding the 2000 listeners???, though without calculating fields as far as I can see)
4. Is the only way to keep the amount of listeners in check by means of limiting the actual quantity of form-field in the active DOM?

I would appreciate any hints & tips that could provide some further information.

The current solution has me separating the form-array into tabs and paginating the arrays on each tab that have more than 50 lines. That works, but I am curious if there are 'cleaner' solutions?

PS: I would appreciate if we could avoid comments like why would you need that many form-fields in the first place. Which, although a legitimate question, does not help as this is a design criteria for rolling it out to the users. If you have constructive information on how to input 7 dayvalues for 600 resources in 1 form then I am all ears?

Comment: You could consider using a single delegated event listener that handles multiple elements.

Comment: @James That sounds interesting, would you be able to provide a linke to some more background information on to implement that?

Comment: What you are using currently for binding the data array in the template - FormBuilder/Reactive form or Template-driven/[(ngModel)]? Also, are you using `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`?

Comment: Using Reactive Forms, ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush, each line item form is detached from ChangeDetectionRef and the detectChanges() is triggered manually after a single call from a method in the line-item. So the amount of listeners that are actually initiated in the form are kept to a minimum. But that strategy doesn't seem to reduce the actual JS listeners (as displayed in Chrome developer window)

Comment: Angular isn't really my thing so I can really only guess at references to link.  I would just google "angular event delegation".  [here's one](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2448-using-jquery-event-delegation-in-angularjs.htm)

Comment: Ok, those are good strategies you are using. I see that you are updating your question. I might not be able to answer this one but I think it would be helpful for others to visualize this if you added some code snippets of your components n templates.

Comment: @Krishnan I will update tomorrow with code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an ideal answer as you are on Angular 6, but I just read about an article that reduces the number of event handlers and change detection cycles in Angular 9. It seems promising, so I hope it works for you, provided you can upgrade your app to v9.

This is using a new option called `ngZoneEventCoalescing`.

“Reduce Change Detection Cycles with Event Coalescing in Angular” by Netanel Basal https://link.medium.com/jG2bFqx3j2

Comment: Many thanks, I'll have a look at it. I did have a brief look into zoning, but haven't implemented something like it, it may be a solution after all. In meantime I've been able to tweak the service settings and insert form fields only when they are relevant to the line. That has reduced the quantity of listeners to about 2000-3000 whilst displaying about 50 lines of resources.

Comment: Cool. Hope it helps.